# Able to print, but can not scan from my printer

Tags: macos, printing

I am using Artisan 725 on my Macbook and when I try to scan it says that the printer is not able to communicate - "Communication error has occurred." However, it will let me print.

Has anybody else had a similar issue with this printer/scanner and found a way to resolve it?

Comment: What model of MacBook? What version of macOS? Have you [downloaded the latest drivers from Epson](https://epson.com/Support/Printers/All-In-Ones/Artisan-Series/Epson-Artisan-725/s/SPT_C11CA74201)?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Epson Artisan 725 is considered an [MFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-function_printer) or [Multi-Function Printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-function_printer).  This means it's actually two separate devices that just share the same footprint.  So, it is entirely conceivable that the printer drivers are readily available from Apple while the scanner driver isn't.

Heading over to their [Support Page](https://epson.com/Support/Printers/All-In-Ones/Artisan-Series/Epson-Artisan-725/s/SPT_C11CA74201?review-filter=macOS%2010.12.x), it appears that they have both printer **AND** scanner drivers for macOS (Sierra) so you would need to install that driver for your scanner to work.

[image]

Comment: I downloaded these but still get the same error...

Comment: @ACE Why not include these details in the question. The answer by Allen is great and +1 so be sure to support good answers even if they aren't your specific answer.